# PortUnreachableException на AVD-эмуляторе планшета

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: на эмуляторах планшета при попытке получить UDP пакет вылетает `java.net.PortUnreachableException`. C эмулятором телефона и на реальном устройстве все ок. 
Это баг эмулятора или же стоит искать причину в коде?

Вылетает вот на этой строке:

```
bytesRead = ((ReadableByteChannel) this.channel).read(this.buffer);
```

UPD настройки AVD:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: настройки AVD планшета в студию!

Comment: @metalurgus Проблема возникает на самых различных настройках. Например, вот http://ipic.su/ajBuA.png